# Need of some explanations about a common sentence in GLM world

Tags: least-squares, parameter-estimation, maximum-likelihood

I read in some books and web pages:

"GLM are fitted with MLE (maximum likelihood estimators) estimators rather than OLS (ordinary least squares)"

I have searched a little bit more and have found something like:

_ When error structure is not normal, LS technique can be difficult.

_ When link function is not identity, LS technique can be difficult.

_ In some GLM different from normal standard one, estimates from MLE and those from OLS are different in general, why ? and why do we prefer estimate parameter of a GLM with those from maximum likelihood?

---> I would like deeper explanations than these ones :(

Thanks !